# In Linux , The reference assemblies for framework ".NETFramework,Version=v4.5" were not found

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio

I have made a setup of Visual studio to compile C# code in my Ubuntu Machine .
I loaded the workspace/my code to VS and I could see the below error.

```
    The reference assemblies for framework ".NETFramework,Version=v4.5" were not found. To resolve this, install the SDK or Targeting Pack for this framework version or retarget your application to a version of the framework for which you have the SDK or Targeting Pack installed. Note that assemblies will be resolved from the Global Assembly Cache (GAC) and will be used in place of reference assemblies. Therefore your assembly may not be correctly targeted for the framework you intend.
```

Please help me on resolving this issue as am a beginner in Visual studio.

Thanks

Comment: You can't use .net framework v4.5 on Linux. You have to use .net core.

Comment: @suchoss Thanks for the reply . Could you please help me in how to migrate to .net core ?

Comment: @suchoss The Mono projects allows to do so, without downgrading to .NET core.

Comment: @Alejandro I've never worked with mono, so I can't really say. But there is already an answer for change to .net core.

Comment: If you are truly a beginner of .NET Framework, stick to Windows and Visual Studio there. If you have no plan to learn .NET Core (why cannot you even google where to learn it), don't even think of playing Mono on Linux. Focus and don't waste your time.

Answer (score 3):

If project is heavy, you can follow
[this procedure](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/porting/)

If your project is lightweight, create a new .netcore project using VS and move your code (and dependencies references)into that new project. then let VS telling you potential errors and correct them.

Looking at the procedure, you can firstly retargeting your actual project in dotnet 4.6.2 framework in order to "ensures that you can use API alternatives for .NET Framework-specific targets in the cases where .NET Core can't support a particular API."

Comment: I could see some installables in the left side . I installed .net core . After that I changed the framework from  v4.5  to .netcore . Now a new issue came like below :  /usr/share/dotnet/sdk/2.1.300/Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(83,5): error MSB4184: The expression "[Microsoft.Build.Utilities.ToolLocationHelper]::GetPathToStandardLibraries(.NETFramework, netcoreapp2.1, '', '', '')" cannot be evaluated. Input string was not in a correct format. [/home/teuser/Desktop/Task on Set-top Box/newEthos/TeSkyEthos/DataEngine/DataEngine.csproj

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend running the portability tool in Visual Studio 2017 if you have it.  This will give you an idea if you will have a hard time moving it over.

As for your error with the csproj, that's because that file has paths within it, which are pointing to locations using windows paths, instead of Linux paths.