# .net core in Linux - build C#

Tags: c#, linux, .net-core

Linux Environment - Ubuntu 16.04 LTS. i have installed .net core 2.1300 (latest, with sdk).

I am trying to build (dotnet build) a .csproj file in C#.

```
So $: dotnet build CarLibTool.2010.csproj
```

But the error is:

```
/usr/share/dotnet/sdk/2.1.300/Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(1179,5): error MSB3644: The reference assemblies for framework ".NETFramework,Version=v4.6.1" were not found. To resolve this, install the SDK or Targeting Pack for this framework version or retarget your application to a version of the framework for which you have the SDK or Targeting Pack installed. Note that assemblies will be resolved from the Global Assembly Cache (GAC) and will be used in place of reference assemblies
```

What possible solutions exists?

maybe change .csproj  ?

Comment: You can't build or run .NET Framework projects on Linux - only .NET Core/Standard projects are supported.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [In Linux , The reference assemblies for framework ".NETFramework,Version=v4.5" were not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50741468/in-linux-the-reference-assemblies-for-framework-netframework-version-v4-5-w)

Comment: If you want to see my .csproj file then: http://collabedit.com/3sswr

Comment: You do not target .Net core  in that file.

Comment: NielsNet, so which thing am i supposed to change and from which file ? Thanks

Comment: @Steve21 there are guides that show how to [port](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/porting/) .NET Framework projects to .NET Core. If you want to create a *new* project, all you need to do is write `dotnet new` and the project type. Typing `dotnet new` without other arguments lists the installed project types. One possibility is to create a new project and copy the old files to it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to build a full .NET (v4.6.1) application on a .NET Core platform and that is not supported.

You need to create a new project (or solution) that targets .NET Core and not .NET 4.6.1 framework.

If you need to share code libraries between a .NET framework (in your case 4.6.1) and .NET Core you should use a .NET Standard library since this can be used by both.

Note that not everything in 4.6.1 will be supported in .NET Core (which is why it's called 'core' because it's only the core functions).  This includes any GUI components you may be using.

Answer (score 3):

As of 6 May, 2019 you could add Nuget package `Microsoft.NETFramework.ReferenceAssemblies` which allow you to build your .NET project on Linux without conversion to .NET Core.